# How to create broken vertical bar graphs in matplotlib?

Tags: python, graph, charts, matplotlib

I'd like to create a broken vertical bar graph in matplotlib.

To give a better idea of the result I'm after, I put an example together with [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/):

[image]

I've had a look at the matpltolib [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/contents.html) and [examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) but I can't seem to find the appropriate chart type to use. The only thing that looks remotely similar is the [boxplot](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo3.html) but this isn't what I need.

- I'd rather not have to draw the graph manually with graphics primitive.
- I can massage the data into shape as needed.

*PS: If you know of a good library that does this in another language (javascript, for example), I'd be grateful for the pointer too.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you have a few series of start datetimes and stop datetimes.

In that case, just use `bar` to plot things, and tell matplotlib that the axes are dates.

To get the times, you can exploit the fact that matplotlib's internal date format is a float where each integer corresponds to 0:00 of that day. Therefore, to get the times, we can just do `times = dates % 1`.

As an example (90% of this is generating and manipulating dates. The plotting is just a single call to `bar`.):

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

def main():
    start, stop = dt.datetime(2012,3,1), dt.datetime(2012,4,1)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for color in ['blue', 'red', 'green']:
        starts, stops = generate_data(start, stop)
        plot_durations(starts, stops, ax, facecolor=color, alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()

def plot_durations(starts, stops, ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    # Make the default alignment center, unless specified otherwise
    kwargs['align'] = kwargs.get('align', 'center')

    # Convert things to matplotlib's internal date format...
    starts, stops = mpl.dates.date2num(starts), mpl.dates.date2num(stops)

    # Break things into start days and start times 
    start_times = starts % 1
    start_days = starts - start_times
    durations = stops - starts
    start_times += int(starts[0]) # So that we have a valid date...

    # Plot the bars
    artist = ax.bar(start_days, durations, bottom=start_times, **kwargs)

    # Tell matplotlib to treat the axes as dates...
    ax.xaxis_date()
    ax.yaxis_date()
    ax.figure.autofmt_xdate()
    return artist

def generate_data(start, stop):
    """Generate some random data..."""
    # Make a series of events 1 day apart
    starts = mpl.dates.drange(start, stop, dt.timedelta(days=1))

    # Vary the datetimes so that they occur at random times
    # Remember, 1.0 is equivalent to 1 day in this case...
    starts += np.random.random(starts.size)

    # Make some random stopping times...
    stops = starts + 0.2 * np.random.random(starts.size)

    # Convert back to datetime objects...
    return mpl.dates.num2date(starts), mpl.dates.num2date(stops)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

On a side note, for events that start on one day and end on the next, this will extend the y-axis into the next day.  You can handle it in other ways if you prefer, but I think this is the simplest option.

Comment: That's brilliant Joe! It's exactly what I was looking for and you gave a great code example. Thank you.